# How to get Goal Funnel Step data such as "entered" and "proceeded" through Query API?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

When looking at Goal Funnel report in the Google Analytics website. I can see not only the number of goal starts and completion but also how many visits to each step.

How can I find the step data through the Google Analytics API?

I am testing with the query explorer and testing on a goal with 3 steps, which 1st step marked as Required

I was able to get the start and completion by running by using goalXXStarts and goalXXCompletions:

> https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A90593258&start-date=2015-09-12&end-date=2015-10-12&metrics=ga%3Agoal7Starts%2Cga%3Agoal7Completions

However I can't figure out a way to get the goal second step data.

I tried using `ga:users` or `ga:uniquePageViews` with the URL of the step 2, and previousPagePath as step 1 (required = true) and add to that the `ga:users` or `ga:uniquePageViews` from the next stage with `ga:previousPagePath` of step 1 (since its required=true) for backfill.

I also tried other combinations, but could never reach the right number or close to it.

Comment: would ga:goalPreviousStep1 ga:goalPreviousStep2, and ga:goalPreviousStep3 work for your needs? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=goal_conversions&jump=ga_goalpreviousstep1

Comment: I tried that as well. perhaps i am not doing it right. i did a get on ga:goalXXStarts with filter on ga:goalPreviousStep1 equals the url of the actual goal step 2, or the same on goalPrevisouStep2 or goalPrevisouStep3. Still the number is lower than in the GAF report on google 
filter: ga:goalCompletionLocation=~^/account-setup/$;ga:goalPreviousStep1=~^/free-trial/$,ga:goalPreviousStep1=~^/free-trial/?.*$,ga:goalPreviousStep2=~^/free-trial/$,ga:goalPreviousStep2=~^/free-trial/?.*$,ga:goalPreviousStep3=~^/free-trial/$,ga:goalPreviousStep3=~^/free-trial/?.*$

Answer (score 0):

One technique that can be used to perform conversion funnel analysis with the Google Analytics Core Reporting API is to define a [segment](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments-feature-reference#conditions) for each step in the funnel. If the first step of the funnel is a ['required'](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2976313?hl=en) step, then that step must also be included in segments for each of the subsequent steps.

For example, if your funnel has three steps named A, B, and C, then you will need to define a segment for A, another for B, and another again for C.

If step A is required then:

- Segment 1: viewed page A,
- Segment 2: viewed page A and viewed page B,
- Segment 3: viewed page A and viewed page C.

Otherwise, if step A is NOT required then:

- Segment 1: viewed page A,
- Segment 2: viewed page B,
- Segment 3: viewed page C.

To obtain the count for each step in the funnel, you perform a query against each segment to obtain the number of `sessions` where that segment matches. Additionally, you can query the previous and next pages, including entrances and exits, for each step (if you need to); in which case, query `previousPagePath` and `pagePath` as dimensions along with metrics `uniquePageviews`, `entrances` and `exits`. Keep in mind the difference between ['hit-level' vs 'session-level' data](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033861?hl=en#ValidDimensionMetricCombinations) when performing, constructing and interpreting the results of each query.

You can also achieve similar results by using [sequential segmentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments-feature-reference#sequences) which will offer you finer control over how the funnel steps are counted, as well as allowing for non-sequential funnel analysis if required.